# angularjs i18n project setup

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just started with angularjs yesterday so assume I know nothing about it.  The first thing I'm attempting to do is put all the labels for my UI into a file (so that we can swap them out for i18n).

From what I understand this is doable by importing the js file and then adding the function that contains the labels as a controller in the html, like this:

```
<html ng-app>
...
<script src="js/i18n/en-US.js"></script> <!-- function inside this named lang -->
...
<body>
... <!-- some html -->
<div ng-controller="lang">
<label class="span5">{{nameOfLabelVar}}</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This all works.  But I'm a bit lost when it comes to code organisation now.  Inside that div are some choice menus that I'll want to use angular on too.

I'd like the js code for the labels to be in one file and the view logic for the page to be in a different js file (name-of-that-page-view-model.js).  I'm unsure as to how to accomplish this.  From what I can tell you cannot nest ng-controller tags and I cannot add them to the specific  tag that it would be for.

It would be nice to be able to have one global controller that sort of imports all of the other js files for the page.

I bet this is baked into the framework and I've missed it, so a nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I am doing my i18n work, it seems to be working great! It is based off a set of localized resource files that get initialized at runtime.

#### I18n module to hold string id map and parameter insertion

```
.factory('I18n', ['$http', 'User', function($http, User) {
    // Resource File
    var LANG_FILE;

    // Fetch Resource File
    function init() {
        return $http.get('resources/locales/' + User.locale + '.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                LANG_FILE = response.data;
            });
    }

    function lang(stringId, params) {
        var string = LANG_FILE[stringId] || stringId;

        if (params && params.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                string = string.replace('%' + (i + 1), params[i]);
            }
        }

        return string;
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        lang: lang
    };

}]);
```

This can be initialized using a .run block

```
.run(['I18n', function(I18n) {
    I18n.init();
}]);
```

And used anywhere to translate a string like this

```
.controller(['$scope', 'I18n', function($scope, I18n) {
    $scope.title = I18n.lang(some_string_id);
}]);
```

#### Custom i18n DIRECTIVE to handle one time translations

```
.directive('i18n', ['I18n', function(I18n) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, $el, attrs) {
            $el[0].innerHTML = I18n.lang(attrs.i18n);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Which can be used like this.

```
<div i18n="some_string_id"></div>
```

#### Custom PLURALIZE directive that matches string ids from your resource file with the count as the parameter.

```
.directive('pluralize', ['I18n', function(I18n) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            count: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $el, attrs) {
            var when  = JSON.parse(attrs.when)
              , param = [$scope.count];
            if (when[$scope.count]) {
                $el[0].innerHTML = I18n.lang(when[$scope.count], param);
            } else {
                $el[0].innerHTML = I18n.lang(when['other'], param);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

And can be used like this.

```
<div pluralize count="{{obj.count}}" when="{1:'single_item','other': 'multiple_item'}"></div>
```

#### The String Resource file would be located at resources/locales/en-US.json, and would look something like this.

```
{
    some_string_id: 'This is in English',
    single_item: '%1 item',
    multiple_item: '%1 items'
}
```

The other locales would have the same string ids, with different translated texts.

Answer (score 5):

after doing a lot of research, here is my 2 cents:
my personal conclusion is that [angular-translate](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate) library is the best for me so far.
There are a lot of nice solutions like that [library](https://github.com/zeflasher/angularjs-i18n) that merges 2 tutorials on that subject. 
But angular-translate has every requirement i've needed:

- Install through bower
- JSON files support in a structure that i prefer
- Easy initialisation
- Checking browser culture
- Change culture in running time
- Great translation loader
- Great documentation
- most popular, biggest community and the only one who is still
  maintained frequently

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2):

For a more flexible base, checkout http://angular-translate.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think that this link:

[(bruno's i18n approach in angular js)](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/internazionalization-i18n-with-angularjs)

Answers your questions pretty well.  His approach is similar in concept to what you want to do, but I think that his implementation, which involves filters, allows you to use constructions like

```
<span class="author">{{ 'WRITTENBY' | i18n }} Bruno</span>
```

Instead of the simpler tags that you suggest.  Read his article and see if it answers your question, but I think it does.